# Passing cv::Mat by reference or return it?

Tags: c++, opencv, return, pass-by-reference

I was wondering which version of this function is more efficient:

```
void myimread (cv::Mat &mat, const std::string &imgname){
  mat = imread(imgname);
}
```

or

```
cv::Mat myimread (const std::string &imgname){
  return imread(imgname);
}
```

From my knowledge, `cv::Mat` is kinda of a smart pointer and combined with the move semantic that `cv::Mat` should implement (again, if I'm not wrong) the second version should be not more expensive than the first one.

Comment: The only way to have an accurate answer is benchmarking and/or checking the generated assembly. I agree that the second one shouldn't be slower than the first one.

Comment: Anyway, the second way is more clear about its intent: the `cv::Map` is what the function builds. As there is no evidence of terrible performances, readability should be prefered to early low level optimisation...

Comment: yes, cv::Mat is similar to a smart pointer, but still it should be more expensive if a (copy-) constructor is called compared to a case where no (copy-) constructor is called. There are some initializations and value settings and stuff, but the main part of the image, all the pixel data, isn't copied and therefore cv::Mat constructors typically are not a bottleneck at all. From readability and usability I would recommend the second version. And maybe I would make that `std::string &` a `const std::string &` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) gets applied, the 2nd case would be more efficient.

For the 1st case, the usage would be:

```
cv::Mat mat;            // default constructed
myimread(mat, imgname); // copy assigned by imread(imgname) inside myimread
```

For the 2nd case:

```
cv::Mat mat = myimread(imgname); // mat is constructed by imread(imgname) directly; copy/move operation is omitted
```

From C++17 when the operand of a return statement is a prvalue and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that prvalue, copy elision is guaranteed.